# Pandas - Compare 2 dataframes and find nearest values

Tags: python, pandas, gis, pyproj

I have 2 dataframes in Pandas that contain `longitude` and `latitude`. I am trying to loop through each of the rows in the first and find the closest matching `longitude` and `latitude` in the second dataframe.

I have this in `python` so far which I found in another SO post...

```
from math import cos, asin, sqrt

def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2-lat1)*p)/2 + cos(lat1*p)*cos(lat2*p) * (1-cos((lon2-lon1)*p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a))

def closest(data, v):
    return min(data, key=lambda p: distance(v['lat'],v['lon'],p['lat'],p['lon']))

tempDataList = [{'lat': 39.7612992, 'lon': -86.1519681}, 
                {'lat': 39.762241,  'lon': -86.158436 }, 
                {'lat': 39.7622292, 'lon': -86.1578917}]

v = {'lat': 39.7622290, 'lon': -86.1519750}
print(closest(tempDataList, v))
```

I am about to try and modify this for use with my pandas dataframes, but is there a more efficient way to do this with `PyProj` for example?

Does anybody have an example or similar code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be able to do this a little easier if you use GIS library. So, If you're using geopandas and shapely, it will be more comfortable. (pyproj is also used.) Start with the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import Point, nearest_points

tempDataList = [{'lat': 39.7612992, 'lon': -86.1519681}, 
                {'lat': 39.762241,  'lon': -86.158436 }, 
                {'lat': 39.7622292, 'lon': -86.1578917}]

df = pd.DataFrame(tempDataList)

#make point geometry for geopandas
geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df['lon'], df['lat'])]

#use a coordinate system that matches your coordinates. EPSG 4326 is WGS84
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs = "EPSG:4326", geometry = geometry) 

#change point geometry
v = {'lat': 39.7622290, 'lon': -86.1519750}
tp = Point(v['lon'], v['lat'])

#now you can calculate the distance between v and others.
gdf.distance(tp)

#If you want to get nearest points
multipoints = gdf['geometry'].unary_union
queried_point, nearest_point = nearest_points(tp, multipoints)
print(nearest_point)
```